# How to access Hashie

Tags: ruby

How do I access the email field from this [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash)?

```
 #<Hashie::Mash addresses=[] contacts=[#<Hashie::Mash created_by="user_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" date_created="2014-07-13T14:36:32.661000+00:00" date_updated="2015-08-14T14:37:28.027000+00:00" emails=[#<Hashie::Mash email="xyz@example.com" type="personal">]
```

I get this Hashie by doing:

```
 data = @test_find.data
 puts data[0]
```

When I try running `puts data.contacts` I get:

```
undefined method 'contacts' for #<Array:....> (No Method Error)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after confidling with this thing for a while I was able to access it by doing:

```
data[0].contacts[0].emails[0].email
```

A little bit hacky but thats all I needed.

Comment: Hacky? Not at all. It's a direct result of your data being in the shape it is in. `data` is an array. It doesn't have method `contacts`. Did you expect a single element instead of that array?